# Change partition number in golang in NATS deterministic subject token partitioning

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

How can I change runtime deterministic subject token partition number in golang?

For example,in account.conf I have:

> mapping:{ "events.*" "events.{{wildcard(1)}}.{{partition(5,1)}}" }

How can I change 5 to another number in golang without restarting the whole server?